# Modify and customize the wxColourDialog box

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need a dialog box where I can  choose colour, font format, font style, and font size. I mean using wxWidgets (need a dialog with wxColourDialog and wxFontDialog in a same dialog box).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that under Windows the native font selection dialog already allows you to select the font colour too. This is not the case under the other platforms however, so you would need to use the non-native, and hence ugly, `wxGenericFontDialog` there if you really need to select both at once.